# Restful url not picking up id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having troubles with routes. I have defined routes like this:

```
  resource :demo
  resource :subjects
  resource :pages
  resource :sections
```

when i do

```
rake routes
```

it doesn't show right urls. it shows something like

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
         root GET    /                                      demo#index
         demo POST   /demo(.:format)                        demos#create
     new_demo GET    /demo/new(.:format)                    demos#new
    edit_demo GET    /demo/edit(.:format)                   demos#edit
              GET    /demo(.:format)                        demos#show
              PATCH  /demo(.:format)                        demos#update
              PUT    /demo(.:format)                        demos#update
              DELETE /demo(.:format)                        demos#destroy
     subjects POST   /subjects(.:format)                    subjects#create
 new_subjects GET    /subjects/new(.:format)                subjects#new
edit_subjects GET    /subjects/edit(.:format)               subjects#edit
              GET    /subjects(.:format)                    subjects#show
              PATCH  /subjects(.:format)                    subjects#update
              PUT    /subjects(.:format)                    subjects#update
              DELETE /subjects(.:format)                    subjects#destroy
        pages POST   /pages(.:format)                       pages#create
    new_pages GET    /pages/new(.:format)                   pages#new
   edit_pages GET    /pages/edit(.:format)                  pages#edit
              GET    /pages(.:format)                       pages#show
              PATCH  /pages(.:format)                       pages#update
              PUT    /pages(.:format)                       pages#update
              DELETE /pages(.:format)                       pages#destroy
     sections POST   /sections(.:format)                    sections#create
 new_sections GET    /sections/new(.:format)                sections#new
edit_sections GET    /sections/edit(.:format)               sections#edit
              GET    /sections(.:format)                    sections#show
              PATCH  /sections(.:format)                    sections#update
              PUT    /sections(.:format)                    sections#update
              DELETE /sections(.:format)                    sections#destroy
              GET    /:controller(/:action(/:id(.:format))) :controller#:action
```

none of the urls has :id in them. what i might be doing wrong? It still sends id to controller but i am having hard time calling index and show methods as both of them are mapped to -----#show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using [singular resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources), e.g. `resource :foo`.  When you use singular resource, you don't get the `:id`.  In order to get the `:id` in the parameter, you should change the resources declarations to plural `resources`:

```
resources :demoes
resources :subjects
resources :pages
resources :sections
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am just a beginner.